# How to show message if folder contains different extensions along with my .Dat file?

Tags: c#

I have to show a message, if my folder contains .Dat files and other 
extension files. how to do this . Need help appreciated

```
      private void btnChooseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo[] files;
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        //fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        fbd.SelectedPath = @txtFilepath.Text.Trim();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFilepath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            if (rbtnOffline.Checked)
            {
                DefaultManager.OfflineFilePath = @txtFilepath.Text.ToString().Trim();
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(DefaultManager.OfflineFilePath);
                files = info.GetFiles("*.dat").OrderBy(p => p.LastWriteTime).ToArray();

                if (files.Count() > 0)
                {
                    //   MessageBox.Show("no error");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error, Incorrect capture folder selected", "PGY-SSM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    //txtFilepath.Clear();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DefaultManager.DumpFilePath = @txtFilepath.Text.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: Actually, In my code, if i dont have .dat file count, then im saying inccorect folder.. but what i wanted is,, if i have other files along with .dat files it should say error message

Comment: Getfiles() takes oly one file if i am not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if there are any other files in the folder, compare the total number of files in the folder with the number of dat files:

```
int fileCount = info.GetFiles().Length;
int datFileCount = info.GetFiles("*.dat").Length;

if (fileCount != datFileCount)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Error, other files found …");
}
```